# Pasar parametros a funcion sin importar el orden PHP

Tags: php

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy aprendiendo un poco de python y tengo un poco de conocimientos en php, pero por ejemplo en python se puede pasar a una función el orden de las variables como la persona quiera, ejemplo de a lo que me refiero:

```py
def datos(nombre, apellidos, edad):
    return f"{nombre} {apellidos} tiene {edad} años"
    
print(datos(apellidos="Flores García", nombre="David", edad=14))
```

¿Esta característica solo esta en python o también la podría aplicar a otros lenguajes como php, y si se puede como sería? Desde ya gracias

Comment: La única manera que conozco de hacer eso,es que envíes los parámetros en un array `mifuncion($arraydeparametros)`

Comment: Creo que a partir de la [versión 8](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) han implementado esta feature

Comment: @EugeniBejan intente hacerlo como tu dijiste pero cuando lo abro en la página me da este error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 10` y ya verifique tener php8 instalado

Comment: Comprueba que no tengas nada raro por ahí. [Aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1aa1547cd3fef85b1cde61de1f8ec50b02c39f2c) tienes un ejemplo

Comment: @EugeniBejan al parecer todo esta bien, el problema es la version de php que usa mi servidor web, ya hice una pregunta para que me ayuden a cambiarla

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con Python, removeré la etiqueta