# Problemas al cambiar de version php

Tags: php, php8

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que mientras alguien me ayudaba a resolver [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500671/pasar-parametros-a-funcion-sin-importar-el-orden-php) me tuve que instalar php 8, eso fue bien ya que si pongo en mi terminal `php --version` si me sale que tiene la 8, el problema es que apache no reconoce que estoy usando php8 y me deja usando php7, lo que genera problemas en página, quiero decir que estoy en linux, en deepin, ¿alguien me podría ayudar a decir como puedo cambiar la version de php que usa apache? es que no he podido encontrar información de ayuda en otro lugar. Desde ya gracias :).

### Edit

Después de hacer lo que dijo Triby, lo que esta en los comentarios, en la consola me salía esto:

```
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php8.0:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php8.0:
Enabling module php8.0.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
```

Y cuando abro mi página me sale este error:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

### Edit 2

Este edit lo añadí ya que intente hacer la respuesta que me dio Triby, todo estaba yendo bien pero casí al final al querer restablecer apache, usano `sudo systemctl restart apache2` me da este error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

¿Me podrían ayudar a ver que pasa y como arreglarlo?

### Edit 3

Me sugirieron en los comentarios intentar con los comandos `systemctl status apache2.service` y `journalctl -xe`, esta es la salida del comando `systemctl status apache2.service`:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-02 08:06:20 CST; 8min ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 5347 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable
```

Y esta es la salida de `journalctl -xe`:

```
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
dic 02 08:14:24 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 18874374 is nil
dic 02 08:14:24 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 18874374
dic 02 08:14:24 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 25166056
dic 02 08:14:24 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:24 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:24 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:25 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 18874389
dic 02 08:14:25 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 18874389
dic 02 08:14:34 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:34 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:34 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:35 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 25166059 is nil
dic 02 08:14:35 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 18874374 is nil
dic 02 08:14:35 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:35 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:35 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:14:36 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 18874374
dic 02 08:14:36 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 25166059
dic 02 08:14:44 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 67108903 is nil
dic 02 08:14:45 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 67108906 is nil
dic 02 08:14:45 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 67108905 is nil
dic 02 08:14:46 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 67108903
dic 02 08:14:47 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 67108905
dic 02 08:14:47 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 67108906
dic 02 08:15:03 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:15:03 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:15:03 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:15:04 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 25166062 is nil
dic 02 08:15:04 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_entries.go:177: entry of window 18874374 is nil
dic 02 08:15:05 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:15:05 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:15:05 davebook-Linux x-event-monitor[6112]: manager.go:130: <nil>
dic 02 08:15:05 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 25166062
dic 02 08:15:05 davebook-Linux daemon/dock[6112]: dock_manager_xevent.go:209: mapNotifyEvent after 2s, call identifyWindow, win: 18874374
```

### Edit 4

Este edit lo añadí ya que quería ver si realmente tenia php instalado, pero al intentar usar `php --version` me sale este error:

> bash: php: orden no encontrada

Pero si intento descargarlo como dijo Triby en su respuesta me dice esto:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-readline» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-cli» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-tokenizer» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-posix» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-iconv» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-ffi» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-ftp» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-sysvmsg» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-exif» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-sysvsem» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-sysvshm» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-pdo» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-sockets» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-shmop» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-opcache» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-ctype» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-calendar» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-fileinfo» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-common» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-json» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-phar» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «libapache2-mod-php8.0» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
Nota, seleccionando «php8.0-gettext» para la expresión regular «php8.0»
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
```

Entonces creo que el problema es que no tengo php instalado correctamente, ¿alguien me puede decir de que otra forma lo puedo instalar?

**Mini edit**

Al probar el comando `apache2ctl configtest` me sale este error:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax
> error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8.0.load: Cannot load
> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so into server:
> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error
> log may have more information.

Y esto es lo que muestra el **error.log**:

```
[Wed Dec 01 17:12:28.522923 2021] [core:notice] [pid 9217] AH00052: child pid 9264 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 01 17:12:28.522959 2021] [core:notice] [pid 9217] AH00052: child pid 9265 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 01 17:12:28.522966 2021] [core:notice] [pid 9217] AH00052: child pid 9266 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Dec 01 17:22:57.794578 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9217] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
corrupted size vs. prev_size while consolidating
[Wed Dec 01 17:23:59.890755 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4687] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Uos) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 01 17:23:59.984771 2021] [core:notice] [pid 4687] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Dec 01 17:41:53.319103 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4687] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
corrupted size vs. prev_size while consolidating
[Wed Dec 01 17:42:54.112847 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5040] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Uos) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 01 17:42:54.288360 2021] [core:notice] [pid 5040] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Dec 01 21:36:30.893579 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5040] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
corrupted size vs. prev_size while consolidating
[Wed Dec 01 21:36:31.025352 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17953] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Uos) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 01 21:36:31.025475 2021] [core:notice] [pid 17953] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Dec 01 21:46:38.171681 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17953] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Dec 01 21:46:38.215550 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27299] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Uos) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 01 21:46:38.238747 2021] [core:notice] [pid 27299] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Dec 01 21:47:11.500808 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 27299] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta, ¿PHP 7 se ejecuta como módulo de Apache?, entonces debes deshabilitarlo desde la terminal con `sudo a2dismod php`, habilitar PHP 8 con `sudo a2enmod php8.0`, después, reinicias Apache y debe funcionar sin problema.

Comment: @Triby despues de hacer lo que me dijiste no carga la página, voy a editar la pregunta con la información

Comment: @Triby listo, añadí toda la información

Comment: @Triby si, ya ejecuté ese comando mas de una vez y por si acaso hice `sudo systemctl start apache2` pero sigue igual :(

Comment: Ejecuta los comandos sugeridos: `systemctl status apache2.service` y `journalctl -xe` para ver los errores y, de ser necesario, cópialos y agrégalos en la pregunta.

Comment: @Triby listo, ya añadí esa información :)

Comment: Esperaba ver un mensaje descriptivo, pero parece que el problema está en otro lado. Tal vez encuentres algo útil en `/var/log/apache2/error.log` o ejecutando el comando `apache2ctl configtest`. Podría ser solo un error de configuración.

Comment: @Triby creo que ya se cual es el error, creo que no tengo bien instalado php8, deja edito la pregunta con mas información

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131981/discussion-between-triby-and-david-flores-garcia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes un archivo `.htaccess`, bórralo, renómbralo o muévelo a otra carpeta, solo para evitar que alguna directiva esté ocasionando conflictos y revisa si ya funciona.

### ¿Errores de PHP?

Por defecto, PHP no muestra los errores y es probable que tu script esté fallando, por lo que hay que tratar de mostrar los mensajes en el navegador. Desde la terminal ejecuta:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Presiona CTRL+w para buscar y modifica las siguientes variables para quedar con estos valores:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Presiona CTRL+s para guardar y CTRL+x para salir. Reinicia Apache nuevamente y verifica si funciona.

### ¿Aún hay errores?

Sigue estos pasos para tratar de solucionar el problema:

1. Crea un punto de restauración. Sí, suena raro, pero con [timeshift](https://wiki.debian.org/timeshift) puedes lograrlo.
2. Deshabilita los módulos de PHP, solo por si acaso

```
sudo a2dismod php
sudo a2dismod php8.0
```

3. Desinstala las dos versiones de PHP

Para desinstalar PHP7

```
sudo apt remove php libapache2-mod-php
```

Para desinstalar PHP 8 y cualquier extensión que haya quedado de PHP 7 (Comando basado en la respuesta de [este enlace](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why/)):

```
sudo apt remove '^php.*'
```

**Importante:** Para desinstalar completamente la versión anterior y sus configuraciones, prueba con:

```
sudo apt purge php8.0
```

4. Si ya agregaste los repositorios de PHP 8.0, ignora esa parte, lo mismo con las líneas que comienzan con `#`, porque son comentarios (Lista de comandos tomada de [este enlace](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-on-debian-linux/)):

```
# Omitir esta parte si ya tienes las dependencias y repositorio
# Actualizar repositorios
sudo apt update
# Si hay algo por actualizar ejecuta el siguiente comando
sudo apt upgrade -y
# Si hubo actualizaciones, de preferencia reinicia el equipo

# Instalar dependencias requeridas
sudo apt install -y lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common gnupg2
# Agregar repositorio de PHP 8.0
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sury-php.list
# Importar clave del repositorio
wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
# Actualizar repositorios para aplicar el de PHP 8.0
sudo apt update

# Comenzar instalación
sudo apt install php8.0 -y

# Si requieres extensiones, puedes agregarlas con php8.0-extension
# Por ejemplo:
sudo apt instal php8.0-mbstring -y
```

De acuerdo al enlace en el que me basé, `libapache2-mod-php8.0` se va a instalar y no es necesario incluirlo, pero puedes verificar que ya está instalado ejecutando `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.0 -y` y te debe dar un mensaje de que ya está instalado en su versión más reciente.

Ahora, hay que verificar que el módulo está activado:

```
# Primero reinicia Apache
sudo systemctl restart apache2
# Listar módulos habilitados
apachectl -M
# Si en la lista no aparece php8_module (shared), tratar de habilitar
sudo a2enmod php8.0
# Reiniciar nuevamente Apache
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

En caso de seguir teniendo problemas, revisa que en la carpeta `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` existen los archivos `php8.0.load` y `php8.0.conf`.

Ejecuta `sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8.0.load`, toma nota del módulo y ruta, que debe ser algo como:

```
LoadModule php8_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so
```

Finalmente, revisa que el archivo existe en esa ruta.

**Importante:** En caso de errores, ejecuta nuevamente timeshift para restaurar el sistema.

### Nota final

Creo recordar que usabas otra distribución de Linux, basada en Ubuntu 20.04 LTS y ahora estás en una basada en Debian, probablemente 11 Bullseye. Si no tienes inconveniente en volver a cambiar de distribución, te recomiendo alguna basada en Ubuntu 21.10, que ya tiene PHP 8 por defecto.

Comment: Triby, al parecer estoy teniendo problemas con timeshift porque hace una copia del equipo entero no? y eso creo que si rompo algo de mi sistema tambien se puede dañar la copia, y respecto a lo del final si usaba una distro basada en ubuntu, el problema es que la rompi y para de paso probar algo nuevo me cambie a deepin, pero entonces ¿la copia es muy pesada no? ¿eso puede afectar en algo al sistema?, espero tu respuesta antes de seguir con tu respuesta. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, timeshift te puede hacer copias del sistema o  incluir también carpetas de datos (home y var), si "rompes" el sistema, la copia queda intacta y puedes volver a como estaba antes. Lo recomendable es guardar los _"snapshots"_ en unidad o partición aparte.

Comment: Triby ok gracias, se que no suele ser aceptado en stackoverflow pero me podrías pasar un tal vez video para ver exactamente que hacer con timeshift? es que me suelo equivocar seguido y no me gustaría equivocarme aquí por eso me gustaría una guía que sea confiable :)

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, no hay problema, [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJOB6fYhvYM) habla de las diferentes opciones de Timeshift. No he tenido necesidad de restaurar, pero creo nuevos puntos de restauración antes de hacer alguna de mis acostumbradas locuras. xD

Comment: Triby jaja muchas gracias, deecho este me va a ayudar mucho ya que como te comenté me cambie a deepin porque rompí kde, y segun dice deepin esta mas enfocado a un usuario final y es mas dificl de romper. Entonces voy a ver el video :)

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, Deepin no me gustó porque cuando lo probé faltaban muchas traducciones y, eso de _"difícil de romper"_ es relativo, depende mucho de lo que hagas como súper usuario. Ahora estoy con Linux Mint, pero en cuanto pueda comprar otro disco duro, probablemente me vaya por Ubuntu Budgie 21.10, es el que me ha parecido más estable, aunque no me gusta que tenga snap.

Comment: Triby, bueno tienes razón depende mucho de lo que hagas como súper usuario, deecho  me volvería a ubuntu pero creo que el disco se puede dañar si lo sobre escribo muchas veces, por eso creo que mejor aprenderé a usar deepin por completo y despues usare otra distro

Comment: Triby edite mi pregunta con un error que me sale al hacer tu respuesta, espero me puedas ayudar :)